# How to pass single param instead of duplication?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refactoring

How correctly refactor function, instead of duplication

so, now I have :

```
export const formatAddressLocation = (postcode, house, additions, street) => {
  let address = "";
  if (street) address += street + " ";
  if (house) address += house + " ";
  if (additions) address += additions + " ";
  if (postcode) address += postcode + " ";
  return address;
};

and
export const formatLocationInfo = (name, postcode, house, additions, street) => {
  let address = "";
  if (name) address += name + " ";
  if (street) address += street + " ";
  if (house) address += house + " ";
  if (additions) address += additions + " ";
  if (postcode) address += postcode + " ";
  return address;
};
```

Something like (location) = {loction.name} + formatAddressLocation(…)

Comment: What does _"single param one param"_ mean? Also, consider passing an object not multiple params?

Comment: You'll need to post a sample of your input and expected output. This can certainly be made more terse.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the name param to the end of the params, and use the second function.

```
export const formatAddressLocation = (postcode, house, additions, street, name) => {
  let address = "";
  if (name) address += name + " ";
  if (street) address += street + " ";
  if (house) address += house + " ";
  if (additions) address += additions + " ";
  if (postcode) address += postcode + " ";
  return address;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params in object

your function would look like this

```
export const formatLocationInfo = ({name, postcode, house, additions, street}) => {
  let address = "";
  if (name) address += name + " ";
  if (street) address += street + " ";
  if (house) address += house + " ";
  if (additions) address += additions + " ";
  if (postcode) address += postcode + " ";
  return address;
};
```

you can call your funtion like

```
let obj = {
   name: "",
   postcode: "",
   house: "",
   additions: "",
   street: "",
}

let address = formatLocationInfo(obj)
```

or

```
let address = formatLocationInfo({name: "", postcode: "", house: "",additions: "", street: ""})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
result = `${locationName ? locationName + ' ' : ''} ${formatAddressLocation(postcode, house, additions, street)}`;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).